# find all non-repeating paths through a set of connected nodes/process diagram

Tags: algorithm, statistics, graph-algorithm, data-analysis

I am trying to understand if its possible in any reasonable way to establish a set of non-repeating paths through a given process diagram.

here are some basic facts about the process diagrams i have:

- they have one or more start points
- they have one or more end points
- all start points have one connector leading from them
- all steps have at least one or more inbound connectors and one or more outbound
  connectors
- if there is more than one of the following each must be
  named:

  - Start terminators
  - End Terminators
  - Connections leading from a step

I have access to all of the data I can imagine being required (finding all start points, getting all connections, names of connections etc).

I basically want to find as many unique paths through the process from start point to end point where you don't go round in a circle repeatedly. so you can go through the same step several times but you cannot repeat a complete circuit more than once in any given route through.

This seems like the type of thing people would have written papers about and have proofs for why it can or cannot be done, I just dont know the magic words I need to google that ;-) Sudo code or similar would be ideal (and amazing) but I am happy to do my own reading if someone can point me in the right direction.

**ANY SEARCH TERMS SUGGESTIONS VERY WELCOME AND GREATLY APPRECIATED**

**Note** I would be interested solutions that suggest lots of extra "silly" possibilities that have to be reviewed by a human afterwards - it would still be interesting to see what it generated.

An bit of an example to clarify things:

```
        G<--2-E<--1-F-2--|
        |     |     ^    |
        |     1     |    |
        |     |     2    |
        \/   \/     |   \/
start--->A--->B---->C-1->D---end
```

some routes through:

- start,A,B,C:1,D,end
- start,A,B,C:2,F:1,E:1,B,C:1,D,end
- start,A,B,C:2,F:1,E:2,G,A,B,C:1,D,end
- start,A,B,C:2,F:2,D,end

nice but what about a more interesting one:

- start,A,B,C:2,F:1,E:2,G,A,B,C:2,F:1,B,C:2,F:2,D,end

I hit C three times and each time I choose option two and there is no repeating.

**Extra points**: I was thinking that I can mark some of the nodes with multiple outbound connectors as being consistent within any given execution of a process.. e.g. if there is a "write code" process that has a decision point "language" with two outbound connectors "c#" and "java" I could say that within any given execution of this process it will always be either c# or java - that will never change during the execution of the process. as opposed to something that may change like "are there bugs?" which on first pass through might have a yes, then on the second pass through (after some fix bugs steps ;-) might have the outcome no.

Do you know any terms or techniques relating to this type of extra analysis / processing / definition?

**EDIT:** I added a example solution implemented in JS as an ansewer based on @Ishtar's answer.

Comment: If you can do a step multiple times then that implies that you can repeat a complete circuit, no?

Comment: not necessarily, you might have branch a & b and in branch a you might have branch 1 & 2. So you could loop through branch a twice: once for sub branch 1 and once for sub branch 2.

Comment: I think that you can get close by doing something that looks at all possible routes until it finds a repeated sequence of steps.. but its about selecting the right start and end point for that sequence and exactly which set of possibilities are you going to cut out. if you had all possible possibilities (impossible they are infinite- just varying the number of times you loop) then you could establish which ones had repeats of the same loop and eliminate them, but i dont know how you set up your code so that you are investigating possibilities.. but stop when a possibility starts looping.

Comment: Do you mean go through the same branch in different paths?

Comment: my comment is not very clear, i have updated the question to have a bit of an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a depth first search? This would walk through all the possible paths. The only difficult part is ignoring paths that would lead to the same cycle again. If you're at a node, you check if you been there before (a cycle), and make sure the same sequence isn't in the path already.

For example

```
start,A,B,C:2,F:1,E:1,B,C:2,F:1,E:1,B
```

From here, we can only go to C. Looking back(the last 4 nodes), we find the cycle `C:2,F:1,E:1,B`. The cycle exists already, so we can't go to node c. Since we can't go anywhere else, this branch doesn't give a correct path.

Pseudocode:

```
allpaths(path,node)
  cycle = path.substring(path.lastIndex(node)) + node
  if path.contains(cycle)
    return
  path = path + node
  if node.isEndNode
    print path
    return
  for child in node.children
    allpaths(path, child)
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking.. if you get to a point you have been to and the steps in between are the same as some previous time then that no good.  But the problem is for that to work when you get to each node you have to complete all possible paths to such a point that you know you have everything but repeats, which is the situation you were in to begin with :-S

Comment: don't suppose you can scratch together some sudo code to show how you might approach something like that? I think this is the answer just I don't know how to code it...yet ;-)

Comment: @gordatron - Did you try it? I think you're making this more complicated than it is... Or maybe I don't understand. Why do you need all possible paths to find a repeated cycle in one path?

Comment: Thanks! I am going to give it a go now.. so if you find a repeated loop you just forget about what you are doing, as all other "unique" possibilities are captured in another recursion.. I think you may be right and I am just thinking about ti too much when I should be coding it ;-)

Comment: nearly finished writing my test.. I guess I need to find all cycles, not just the last one?... coding anyways, I will post the results shortly

Comment: @gordatron I think the last one is sufficient.

Comment: lol I thought JS would be quick to implement this in but I did a schoolboy error! its roughly working but i think it will still get caught out if it has two ways to loop back to the same item, unless I modify it to find all cycles.

Comment: thanks though I consider this answered!... lets see what testing brings up ;-) I will put the JS solution in the question once I have that find all cycles method working

Comment: @gordatron - Thanks! I hope you'll succeed! (Btw, if you put your solution, please post it as an answer.)

Comment: thinking about it again i think that getting all cycles is not needed as your code compares the last loop to all previous loops and every loop will be the last loop when it is first created.

Answer (score 1):

is this relevant? [finding all the elementary circuits of a directed graph](http://dutta.csc.ncsu.edu/csc791_spring07/wrap/circuits_johnson.pdf).  even if it's not the algorithm you use, it may help with appropriate definitions and names.

Comment: reading... i may be some time ;-) thanks though it looks to be a step in the right direction and I will probably learn some good words ;-)

Answer (score 1):

a complete example in a web page of @Ishtars solution, the graph is the one from the question... It seems to work, not extensively tested it. Its a far simpler solution than I was expecting ;-)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function connection(name, endPoint) {
            this.name = name;
            this.endPoint = endPoint;
        }

        function node(name) {
            this.name = name;
            this.connections = [];

            this.addConnection = function (conn) {
                this.connections[this.connections.length] = conn;
            }
        }


        function printPath(path) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 
              document.getElementById('output').innerHTML
              + path + '<br />';
        }

        function allPaths(path, node) {
            if (node.name == "end") {
                printPath(path + ',' + node.name);
                return;
            }
            cycle = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(node.name)) + ',' + node.name;
            if (cycle.length > 1 && path.indexOf(cycle) > 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < node.connections.length; i++) {
               allPaths(path + ',' + node.name + ":" + 
                   node.connections[i].name
                   ,node.connections[i].endPoint);
            }
       }

        var start = new node("start");
        var a = new node("A");
        var b = new node("B");
        var c = new node("C");
        var d = new node("D");
        var e = new node("E");
        var f = new node("F");
        var g = new node("G");
        var end = new node("end");

        start.addConnection(new connection("1", a));
        a.addConnection(new connection("1", b));
        b.addConnection(new connection("1", c));
        c.addConnection(new connection("1", d));
        c.addConnection(new connection("2", f));
        d.addConnection(new connection("1", end));
        f.addConnection(new connection("1", e));
        f.addConnection(new connection("2", d));
        e.addConnection(new connection("1", b));
        e.addConnection(new connection("2", g));
        g.addConnection(new connection("1", a));

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:allPaths('start', a)";>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the output (just in case anyone can spot a mistake ;-):

```
start,A:1,B:1,C:1,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:1,B:1,C:1,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:2,G:1,A:1,B:1,C:1,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:2,G:1,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:2,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:1,B:1,C:2,F:2,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:2,G:1,A:1,B:1,C:1,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:2,G:1,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:1,B:1,C:1,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:2,G:1,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:1,B:1,C:2,F:2,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:1,E:2,G:1,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:2,D:1,end
start,A:1,B:1,C:2,F:2,D:1,end
```

Guess I didn't know about jsFiddle when I wrote this, here is a fiddle with the above code in it:

http://jsfiddle.net/6bWMp/1/

Comment: note: i call it the first time with allPaths('start',a) instead of allPaths('',start) to make the output prettier ;-)